# Avoiding CakePHP's saveAll and using manual query's

Tags: cakephp

I need to update and/or insert 600K records every hour and this is rather problematic (slow) using CakePHP (2.6) saveAll. Using raw query's speeds things up a LOT, but I'm not sure what is the best approach to do this in Cake.

I need to:

1. UPDATE table1 SET price=100,timestamp=$timestamp WHERE product_id=X AND country_id=Y
2. Check if the UPDATE returns any affected rows
3. If yes, OK, move on to the next record
4. If no, INSERT into table1 (price,product_id,country_id,timestamp) VALUES (100,X,Y,$timestamp)

I know i can use $db->rawQuery() but that doesnt give any affected rows when using UPDATEs etc. Any ideas?

Comment: May I suggest using a stored procedure that would do all this work? It will reduce the calls significantly (making this logic inside the procedure) and it should work a lot faster.

Comment: I am not familiar enough with stored procedures but thanks for the suggestion and I will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a cron with pure php, these script work more fast and you can do anything you want.